# Alternative to the unreliable Apple Magic keyboard?

Tags: keyboards, apple

While I am a software engineer, I do not like noisy keyboards and I find the latest Apple Magic Keyboard very prone to typos.

I do use an iMac and an MacBook so I am looking to find a keyboard that does is very close to to that layout (likely Apple oriented due to the ctrl-opt-cmd arangement) that does not have this issue.

Also I effectively love the Magic Trackpad, so it would be prefered if the new keyboard would nicely completent the trackpad.

Any chance of finding one or I have to hope apply will fix the butterfly-effect at some point.

Note: while the older non-butterfly keyboard still produce noises, it is apparently not affected by the same typo-rate, I guess is more of 1/3 of what I do on the new one.

Yeah: I do appreciate **low and silent profiles**.

Answer (score 2):

While this is a PC keyboard, the internet tells me that the ctrl-opt-cmd (or ctrl-super-alt) keys can be remapped in MacOS.

I recommend the [A4-Tech KV300-H](http://a4tech.com/product.aspx?id=82). It is:

- slim
- very soft to touch after a month or two of use  - I barely touch the keys before they register
- ridiculously stable - metal body with rubber feet - to move it you have to lift it, it won't slide even if it's your intention to do so
- cheap enough (around 20 USD in Poland)  that you can treat it as temporary to tide you over
- reliable: I'm a software developer too and one of these is still with me after four years and had no issues and that's the one at work
- as an added bonus it has a built in USB hub

But:

- it has no media keys
- backslash is moved as compared to mac

Answer (score 2):

## Get one of the scissor switch Apple keyboards

Keyboards make noise, and unless you want to get something horrid like a [silicone](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0179N39KS), touchscreen, or [laser](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00X54W9FC) keyboard, you're pretty much stuck with moving parts that are going to make noise. Frankly, **the Apple scissor switches are some of the [quietest (formerly) on the market](https://youtu.be/mP1p7-QeuRU?t=529)**, and you've said that you're fine with the things people normally complain about (layout and feel.) They're dead cheap on the used market (my local electronics thrift shop has them for $5) and it'll have the right layout and keycaps right out of the box. **My only recommendation is to get one of the older wired ones**, as I've found they tend to be somewhat quieter due to the larger contact area and lower distance from the desk.

Sure, there are plenty of other good scissor switch (and even low profile mechanical) keyboards out there, many of which arguably feel better: the [Cherry Stream 3.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B011Z7FMWM), the [Surface Keyboard](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/surface-keyboard/8r3rqvvflp4k/h85z?activetab=pivot:overviewtab), the [Gram XS](http://tesorotec.com/project/gram-xs/), any one of Cougar or Razer's various low profile keyboards. But **they aren't going to beat Apple in terms of being Apple, price, or being quiet.** And hey, if Apple comes out with a new switch in 2020, it's a $5 keyboard.